# OS X Lion All Files Showing as Type of Document

Tags: filesystem, uti

I had an issue where my MacBook Air would not start a couple days back, so I reinstalled the OS. I ran the reinstallation from the recovery partition. Ever since then, almost all of my files show as type "Document", as you can see. Even music does. I do not understand why this is. I even tried reinstalling again and have the same issue. Does anyone know of a fix, this is extremely annoying. I did not have this problem before the reinstallation.

[image]

Comment: It probably won't help in this case, but have you tried [rebuilding the Launch Services database](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071102084155353)?

Comment: yeah :( i can't find anything on the issue. it is so strange.

Comment: If you create a new user on the system, does it show the same problem there as well?

Comment: if i create a new user can i copy settings from one user over to the new user? is there a way to do so?

Comment: what's really odd is, i reinstalled everything, upgraded to mountain lion. everything was fine, BUT its doing the same thing. So somewhere along the way, i changed a setting or installed an application that messed everything up. this is really pissing me off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out a while back but have not been here in a while.

If anyone else is having this issue or an issue similar, the Spotlight preferences is where you will fix this. Apparently the index used for Spotlight is is used for more than just Spotlight.

If everything is checked in Spotlight's preferences this issue will go away.

Comment: Certainly plausible that this would affect the "All My Files" view in Finder, since that's just implemented as a Spotlight search.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried repairing Disk Permissions using the Disk Utility when booted off your Recovery Partition?

Comment: sure have, doesn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with video files showing up as Documents.

I fixed it by getting the app *Onyx*.

Once you get it (make sure it's for the OS X version you are running since latest version is for 10.8 only), go to *Maintenance* >> *Rebuild*.

I checked all options and I remember checking "Display of Folders' contents" particularly.

Next, I clicked on *Cleaning* tap and performed most cleaning scripts.

After that, I did the other maintenance scripts in the app including repairing permissions  and restarted.

That took care of the issue for me.
Hope that helps.

Comment: just tried this, so, now any music in my downloads folder still shows as a document, but it no longer displays the music in my music folder at all. all of the music is still there but it does not display it under "All My Files" this is so weird and so annoying

Comment: now after logging in and out a couple of times they all show back up under documents

Answer (score 0):

You do not say if you checked the Finder preferences to verify the option to "Show all filename extensions" is deselected. I doubt this is your problem as this is not selected by default, but it is worth looking into and might be a simple fix.

1. Select the desktop or a Finder window.
2. Open Finder Preference. File > Preferences.
3. Select the Advanced tab.
4. Uncheck the first option. "Show all filename extensions"

[image]

Comment: i just tried that, it did not do anything for me. I didn't have it checked before i reformatted my drive either. this is the strangest issue. the thing that bothers me the most is that all of my music is listed under documents, when it is obviously music, and before this issue it listed under the category music. I really appreciate the help though. I welcome any and all ideas. I am willing to try anything to get it to work. I might try reinstalling everything again...

Comment: What does it tell you if you "Get Info" on a specific file. Also, when you select - say a music file, will it let you open the file with an appropriate app?